# JQuery $.post() callback failure

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's my JavaScript Code:

```
$.post("Actions.php", {
    'recaptcha': grecaptcha.getResponse(),
    'email': $("#emailInput").val(),
    'Password': $("#passwordConfirm").val(),
},
function(data) {
    console.log(data);
})
```

Now the post request was successfully executed, but `console.log(data)`was ignored by JQuery.
I tried to search for any possible errors from the documents,but nothing found.
Anything wrong with my code?
Thanks.

Comment: That's all of your code?

Comment: Add the `.fail` jqXHR as detailed [here (The jqXHR Object)](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) and [here (jquery.ajax)](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR)

Comment: What else do you need?

Comment: So, the ```$.post()``` request can't execute the callback like this?

Comment: Is that i need ````$.ajax()``` instead of ```$.post()```?

Comment: `So, the $.post() request can't execute the callback like this?` - it can, but only when the HTTP response code indicates a success. As you're not entering that callback the request is failing. You can use the `fail()` handler to determine why, or the network tab of devtools

Answer (score -1):

<s>When providing a `success`, JQuery probably parses your POST data/body object as its `settings` object instead</s>

<s>It should work if you move the callback to a `.done`</s>

edit: mis-read the [jQuery.post documentation](https://api.jquery.com/Jquery.post/), ignore the above

Try adding a handler for both done and fail:

```js
$.post("Actions.php", {
    'recaptcha': grecaptcha.getResponse(),
    'email': $("#emailInput").val(),
    'Password': $("#passwordConfirm").val(),
})
.done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    console.log("Success ", data);
})
.fail(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    console.log("Failed ", textStatus);
});
```

`.done` is run on a 'successful' response, `.fail` for failure responses, and `.always` for any response

Comment: Thanks. But the callback still doesn't working by adding ```.done```....And by the way, My JQuery version is 3.6.0

Comment: Oh but ```.always``` seemed working! Thanks a lot!

Comment: .done -> success, .fail -> error, .always -> always (suprise!)  so yes, `always` always works